# Scope of string in appdomain

Tags: c#, string, appdomain

I know string are immutable, but which **scope** does this immutable (cached?!) string has?
Is it scoped per Appdomain or is the scope bigger (system)? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documantation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern(v=vs.110).aspx), the intern-table for strings is CLR-Scoped, so, strings can even outlive your assembly.

Comment: Very interessting, so you have to reboot system to clear the table or close the application?

Comment: It's enought top stop process (on the other hand, if AppDomain is unloaded, but process still alive, intern-table stills intact)